# Python - Using response.content in async function?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-requests, streamreader

só.

I created a async Class lib, to scrape a large amount of urls, to create my class I used some other code and they used response.text() and was working ok. Today scraping a diferente website, I noticed that some html content was missing so I tried to do the request the normal way and noticed I normally use responste.content while using Request Lib outside my async lib.

This are the defs:

```
    async def fetch(self, session, url):
        try:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                
                # 1. Extracting the Text:
                text = await response.text()
                conection_status = response.status
                # 2. Extracting the infos from the url:
                dict_content = await self.extract_dict_content(text, url,conection_status )
                
                return text, url, dict_content,conection_status
        except Exception as e:
            print('!!!!!! WARNING !!!!')
            print(str(e))
            
            
    async def extract_dict_content(self, text, url,conection_status):
        try:
            
            scraped = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
            return self.scrap_def(scraped, url, conection_status)
  
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

So i tried changing .text() for .content but Im getting this error:
**'StreamReader' object is not callable**

I read that some websites have *like nested code* and when using .text() some text might not appear so I have to use .content to get full HTML code.

Can somebody help me find a solution for this?